# update object value in useState array nested

Tags: reactjs

I have a nested value in array and I want to update value using useState and it is updated but it also create new index value in array which is not required.

```
let data = {
    query: [
      {
        com: "",
        id: 1,
        rules: [{ fN: "tej", sN: "raj" }]
      },
      {}
    ]
  };
```

here I want to update value of fN only but new index [1] created in query at same time. here is link to code - https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-night-kkycxh?file=/src/App.js:103-239

Answer (score 1):

I would do as below, using a state update function, as you are trying just with index `0` it doesn't really matter

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setQuery((prev)=>{
      return prev.map((q,idx)=>{
        if(idx === 0){
          q.rules[0].fN = "ram"
        }
        return q
      })
    });
  }, []);
```